# How to accept space in string in C in the given code

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets, gets

Sorry about the previous code, I did not correctly interpreted the situation.
What's happening is the string is being stored with spaces but when i am trying to read it afterwards, The output flickers continuously (its like its reading it over and over again and printing it infinitely on itself.)

The records are stored in a file named `record.dat`

I am inserting image showing file contents stored after I input a new record in the file (Everything gets stored correctly here)

![These are the contents of record.dat right after i insert the new record]--> the image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxGEd.png

and now when I try to look the details of this record on my application I get this.

![Output showing the record details but not entirely correct as " Finch" is missing] -- >> the image -- >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgmGY.png

and after this if i close the application and then start it again and try to read the previous data it shows this:

![This output is also flickering like before but now even the data is gone]-->> the image -->> http:// i.stack.imgur.com/ 4q0qb.png

(and just in case you are wondering -- the data is still there in the record.dat file -- all of it which i entered when i prevously created the record.)

I hope the problem is more clear now.....

```
void see(void)
{
FILE *ptr;
int test=0,rate;
int choice;
float time;
float intrst;
char c;

ptr=fopen("record.dat","r");
printf("Do you want to check by\n1.Account no\n2.Name\nEnter your choice:");

//Selection Choice with Validation
int once = 0;
do
{   
    if(once!=0)
    {
        printf("\nThe choice is invalid.\nEnter 1 for account number and 2 for name");
    }
    once = once+1;
} while ((scanf("%d%c", &choice, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin());


if (choice==1)
{   
    //Account Number with Validation
    once = 0;
    do
    {   
        if(once!=0)
        {
            printf("\nThe above account number is invalid.\nEnter an account number (numeric value only):");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEnter an account number:");
        }

        once = once+1;
    } while ((scanf("%d%c", &check.acc_no, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin());

    while (fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",&add.acc_no,add.name,&add.dob.month,&add.dob.day,&add.dob.year,&add.age,add.address,add.citizenship,&add.phone,add.acc_type,&add.amt,&add.deposit.month,&add.deposit.day,&add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
    {
        if(add.acc_no==check.acc_no)
        {   system("cls");
            test=1;

            printf("\nAccount NO.:%d\nName:%s \nDOB:%d/%d/%d \nAge:%d \nAddress:%s \nCitizenship No:%s \nPhone number:%.0lf \nType Of Account:%s \nAmount deposited:$ %.2f \nDate Of Deposit:%d/%d/%d\n\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.citizenship,add.phone,
            add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
            if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed1")==0)
                {
                    time=1.0;
                    rate=9;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+1);
                }
            else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed2")==0)
                {
                    time=2.0;
                    rate=11;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+2);

                }
            else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed3")==0)
                {
                    time=3.0;
                    rate=13;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+3);

                }
             else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"saving")==0)
                {
                    time=(1.0/12.0);
                    rate=8;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d of every month",intrst,add.deposit.day);

                 }
             else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"current")==0)
                {

                    printf("\n\nYou will get no interest\a\a");

                 }

        }
    }
}
else if (choice==2)
{   
    printf("Enter the name:");
    scanf("%s",&check.name);

    while (fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/%d %d %s %s %lf %s %f %d/%d/%d",&add.acc_no,add.name,&add.dob.month,&add.dob.day,&add.dob.year,&add.age,add.address,add.citizenship,&add.phone,add.acc_type,&add.amt,&add.deposit.month,&add.deposit.day,&add.deposit.year)!=EOF)
    {
        if(strcmpi(add.name,check.name)==0)
        {   system("cls");
            test=1;
            printf("\nAccount No.:%d\nName:%s \nDOB:%d/%d/%d \nAge:%d \nAddress:%s \nCitizenship No:%s \nPhone number:%.0lf \nType Of Account:%s \nAmount deposited:$%.2f \nDate Of Deposit:%d/%d/%d\n\n",add.acc_no,add.name,add.dob.month,add.dob.day,add.dob.year,add.age,add.address,add.citizenship,add.phone,
            add.acc_type,add.amt,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year);
            if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed1")==0)
                {
                    time=1.0;
                    rate=9;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+1);
                }
            else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed2")==0)
                {
                    time=2.0;
                    rate=11;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+2);

                }
            else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"fixed3")==0)
                {
                    time=3.0;
                    rate=13;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d/%d/%d",intrst,add.deposit.month,add.deposit.day,add.deposit.year+3);

                }
             else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"saving")==0)
                {
                    time=(1.0/12.0);
                    rate=8;
                    intrst=interest(time,add.amt,rate);
                    printf("\n\nYou will get $.%.2f as interest on %d of every month",intrst,add.deposit.day);

                 }
             else if(strcmpi(add.acc_type,"current")==0)
                {

                    printf("\n\nYou will get no interest\a\a");

                 }

        }
    }
}


fclose(ptr);
 if(test!=1)
    {   system("cls");
        printf("\nRecord not found!!\a\a\a");
        see_invalid:
          printf("\nEnter 0 to try again,1 to return to main menu and 2 to exit:");
          scanf("%d",&main_exit);
          system("cls");
             if (main_exit==1)
                menu();
            else if (main_exit==2)
                close();
            else if(main_exit==0)
                see();
            else
                {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\nInvalid!\a");
                    goto see_invalid;}
    }
else
    {printf("\nEnter 1 to go to the main menu and 0 to exit:");
    scanf("%d",&main_exit);}
    if (main_exit==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        menu();
    }

    else
       {

         system("cls");
        close();
        }
```

}

Comment: Try using `getline()`.

Comment: And enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: several of the calls to scanf() are using '%s' format specificier.  and the returned value is not being checked.  The usage of '%s' leaves an open invitation to have buffer overflow/undefined behaviour/seg fault event.  I agrees with @shauryachats, use getline() then remove any trailing '\n' then verify the length is ok, then ue strncpy() to place the input into the struct.  Be sure to clear the struct field to all '\0', perhaps with memset()  first, so trash is not left in the final struct contents

Comment: `fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %d/%d/...` and not checking its return value is a problem.  Recommend reading user and file data via `fgets()`, then scan/parse it.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is not to use scanf since scanf is also vulnerable to buffer overflows. In any case, you are not actually doing any formatting with the scanf call. You can use fgets to read the input into a string and specify the maximum number of characters that you allow. Use something like the following:

```
printf("\nEnter the name: ");
fgets(add.name, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%[^...]` format specifier to read spaces into a string. Here's an example program that hopefully gives you something to work from.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char const* line = "This is a string, 10";
   char text[50];
   int number;

   // Read up to 49 characters not including ',' to text.
   sscanf(line, "%49[^,], %d", text, &number);

   printf("%s, %d\n", text, number);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is a string, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide an example of a failing situation or at least clean up the code and only give us the buggy part.
I see a lot of printf use without \n at the end which I know can be a problem (which may aswell be completely out of the subject here).

Since I've never used scanf I can't tell where your error is but maybe if you reduced your code to the acquisition of the user's input (-> the scanf part) then an attempt to display it (-> the part where your string gets truncated as it meets the first space) we could easily help you fix that problem faster and would be nicer to read.